# How to set the rootViewController with Swift, iOS 7

Tags: ios, swift

I want to set the rootViewController in the app delegate ..

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

     var rootView: MyRootViewController = MyRootViewController()
     //Code to set this viewController as the root view??


     return true

}
```

Comment: its literally the same line of code as in objective c

Comment: Yeah, but I am not really that familiar with Objective-C.

Comment: If your using storyboards you shouldn't need to set the root view controller. If you aren't using storyboards you should be.

Comment: @JackWu Ridiculous statement.

Comment: I have the same question. Don't see why this is downvoted. I have a View in my Storyboard, but I don't know how to make the view appear when the application is run. Dragging the arrow to the view causes a crash.

Comment: Why the snarky downvotes?

Comment: FYI @JackWu, storyboard doesn't appear to provide a clean way to switch entry screens when doing the OAuth 1.x dance.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

     var rootView: MyRootViewController = MyRootViewController()

     if let window = self.window{
            window.rootViewController = rootView
     }

     return true
}
```

Comment: I just used this code on Xcode 7.1, and the compiler stated that since rootView is never mutated, it could be made a constant with the `let` keyword instead of `var`.

Answer (score 45):

If you are using a storyboard and want to set your rootViewController programmatically, first make sure the ViewController has a Storyboard ID in the Identity Inspector.
Then in the AppDelegate do the following:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

   // get your storyboard
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

   // instantiate your desired ViewController
   let rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController") as! UIViewController

   // Because self.window is an optional you should check it's value first and assign your rootViewController
   if let window = self.window {
      window.rootViewController = rootController
   }

   return true
}
```

Comment: i'm using Swift 2.0 and this minor change worked for me in storyboard `let rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController") as UIViewController`

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 2.0:**

```
var window: UIWindow?
 var storyboard:UIStoryboard?

 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

  window =  UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
  window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

  storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let rootController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondVCID")

  if let window = self.window {
   window.rootViewController = rootController
  }
```

Answer (score 12):

In order to get it to show there are some things you need to do if you are not using a storyboard. Inside the AppDelegate inside the function application.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    window = UIWindow(frame: frame)

    let itemsViewControler: UITableViewController = BNRItemsViewController()
    if let window = self.window{
        window.rootViewController = itemsViewControler
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: while the storyboard answer does present the correct controller for me, this answer does fire but I end up with a black screen :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
   if let tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
    {
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
    }
```