# ERROR : perhaps the designated entry point is not set?

Tags: ios, swift

Hello EveryOne I am following [THIS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift) awesome tutorial but I didn't download stater project because I want to create a different app I have done everything where I want to pop up only `CenterViewController`  with Left side `ViewController` Both are in `ContainerViewController` But I got This in my Console:

> 2014-11-19 14:04:46.838 SlideTable[3612:87749] Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?

I also tried [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316966/how-to-set-the-rootviewcontroller-with-swift-ios-7) answer but got same result.

What this error means I have done all the required things as the auther provided at start up project but I didnt found any solution for this.

This is the code for may project.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let containerViewController = ContainerViewController()

    window!.rootViewController = containerViewController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Am I missing something?
I will provide further information if needed.

Answer (score 18):

I have met the same issue and I found the solution:

1. Select the Main.storyboard;
2. Open Attributes inspector and click **Is Initial View Controller** in the View Controller section.

This operation works well for me according to the same error message.

Comment: After checking the box ''Is Initial View Controller''  You will see appearing to the left side of the Storyboard an arrow. This confirme witch Storyboard you did choose to start you app.

Answer (score 7):

The main controller of you app (the entry point), does it have the the "Is Initial View Controller" checked on the right bar? It will show an arrow next to it.

Answer (score 7):

**Update for Xcode 11, and iOS 13.**

In addition to elia's answer, you have to change one more attribute in Info.plist file.

In Info.plist file it is needed to change String value for **Storyboard Name** to the name of your initial file that you want to first appear during launching of the application.

By default value for Storyboard Name is set to "**Main**", and you need to change it.

You can find that attribute in:

Info.plist -> Application Scene Manifest -> Scene Configuration -> Application Session Role -> Item 0 -> Storyboard Name

[image]

Comment: @Fattie Whenever I create a new project the default storyboard is named Main and the Info.plist is set to Main. Therefore this answer is only needed if you rename the storyboard. So I don't see how this applies to "almost all fresh Xcode projects". Can you explain why this answer applies as much as you say? Just trying to understand.

Comment: Ahh!  @HangarRash  I beg your pardon; I assumed the nature of this question is: "So I've **changed the name** of my launch storyboard from the default in Xcode, but it doesn't work".  (And/or "How do I change **which storyboard** launches?") {In the "old days" you'd just change the "UIKit Main Storyboard File Base Name" entry [which now I believe does nothing]; the top given in this question seems to be the "new" tip you need to change to a different launch storyboard.}

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by clicking on

`Product -> Clean Build Folder`

Comment: why this happened ??

Answer (score 3):

When you use more than one `UIStoryboard` and want to init your `UIViewController` **except** the `Main.storyboard` for example `Intro.storyboard`, then you would probably get this error. You must select

```
YourProject  -> TARGETS ->  Deployment Info -> Main Interface
```

In `Main Interface`, there are several `UIStoryboard` that you created for your own project. Choose the right one which contains your `UIViewController`.

I mean

`YourProject -> TARGETS -> General -> Deployment Info -> Main Interface.`

Not  `YourProject -> TARGETS ->  Deployment Info -> Main Interface.`

Answer (score 2):

There exists a compatibility issue between IOS 12 and IOS 13.
So you have to remove the Application Scene Manifest from the info.plist in order for  it to function correctly. Also, you have to remove everything related to scenes from the App Delegate.

Comment: From what I'm trying to do all you need to do is remove the value of UISceneStoryboardFile from the Info.plist.

Answer (score 1):

This is a trip down memory lane (iOS 12) for me, but it the error seems to be complaining about a storyboard file, while you do not seem to be using a storyboard at all! The AppDelegate programmatically instantiates the ContainerViewController instead. If this is the case you should remove the value for `UIKit Main Storyboard File Base Name` in the build settings and mark the App Delegate class as your main entry point:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
...
```